# Is there a way to disable calls to Runtime.checkRestricted on the GAE Java development server under Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine

I'm one of those guys who step through their code a lot during development. Beginning with version 1.6.4 of the GAE Java development server, the server has been instrumented with calls to a function named `Runtime.checkRestricted`. This causes two inconveniences when I step through my code:

1. Whenever I step into a function, the debugger goes into the function `Runtime.checkRestricted` (for which there is no source code) at least once, often multiple times.
2. Whenever I step over a function call which has a large call tree underneath, it takes a very long time for the debugger to come back. (That's always a problem in the Eclipse Java debugger, but now it's really bad.)

For me, all this causes a serious drain on productivity. Is there any way to disable this instrumentation, or at least to prevent the debugger from stepping into it? I am using Eclipse with the GAE plugin.

Comment: Wouldn't setting breakpoints at places just before the pieces of code you want to debug solve your problem?

Comment: alex: You're right, setting breakpoints mitigates the problem, but I'll still be stepping through sizable chunks of code. Therefore, there is still a lot of stepping in and out of Runtime.checkRestricted.

Comment: Thomas, perfect post for me. Exact same question, tracing and getting hiccups on `googleappengine/java/src/main/com/google/appengine/tools/development/agent/runtime/Runtime.java`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a step filter to filter out all step breakpoints you are not interested in. The Eclipse documention [provides a guide how to set up step filter](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/views/debug/ref-usestepfilters.htm).

In your specific case, you will want to add a package filter for com.google.appengine.tools.development.* , as this package and its subpackages contain GAE's Runtime class and RuntimeHelper class. Finally, don't forget to activate the option "Use Step Filters" (Shift + F5).

Comment: By the way: If you want to have source code for Runtime.checkRestricted (and most other GAE-related classes), check-out the sources at http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/checkout to your local folder, then once Eclipse asks you to attach sources, point to that folder.